# NDSolve unable to solve coupled ODE's after specific point

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve a set of coupled differential equations that look like this

```
(*Declaring p,q*)

r = N[Sqrt[2]*100];
end = N[50 Sqrt[2] Pi];
p[t_] = r Sin[N[ Pi/2] + t/r];
q[t_] = r + r Cos[N[ Pi/2] + t/r];
P[t_] = D[p[t], t];
Q[t_] = D[q[t], t];


(*NOW FINDING y[t],x[t]*)
k = 1.33;
dist[t_] = Sqrt[(p[t] - x[t])^2 + (q[t] - y[t])^2];
sqrt[t_] = Sqrt[P[t]^2 + Q[t]^2];
eq2 = {x'[t] == k sqrt[t] (p[t] - x[t])/dist[t]};
eq1 = {y'[t] == k sqrt[t] (q[t] - y[t])/dist[t]};
eqns = {eq1, eq2, y[0] == 0, x[0] == -100};
Rationalize[eqns];
sol = NDSolve[eqns, {y[t], x[t]}, {t, 0, end}];
```

This is the differential equation for a predator (x[t],y[t]) in pursuit of a prey (p[t],q[t]). In this example the prey is running a circular path. I set up the variable t such that it references both the predator,prey's distance along the path they will take.
Whenever I run this it says "NDSolve reached maximum number of steps at 155.some long double". NDSolve always fails at precisely 0.7*end, if I do

```
sol=NDSolve[eqns,{y[t],x[t]},{t,0,end*0.69}]
```

It solves instantaneously.

Answer (score 4):

You have a stiff system. By adding `Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"` and reducing , `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` and increasing `MaxSteps` a little, you can get `NDSolve` to finish with no warnings.

btw, there is no need to throw `N` around every thing. Also, there is no need to make everything a function. Only `x[t]` and `y[t]` need to be functions. Everything else is really just an expression. This makes things simpler. Also better to use `{x,y}` and not `{x[t],y[t]}` with `NDSolve`

```
Clear["Global`*"]
r = Sqrt[2]*100
end = 50 *Sqrt[2]*Pi
p = r *Sin[Pi/2 + t/r]
q = r + r* Cos[Pi/2 + t/r]
P = D[p, t]
Q = D[q, t]

(*NOW FINDING y[t],x[t]*)
k = 133/100;
dist = Sqrt[(p - x[t])^2 + (q - y[t])^2];
sqrt = Sqrt[P^2 + Q^2];
eq2 = x'[t] == k *sqrt*(p - x[t])/dist // Simplify
eq1 = y'[t] == k *sqrt*(q - y[t])/dist // Simplify
eqns = {eq1, eq2, y[0] == 0, x[0] == -100};
sol = NDSolve[eqns, {y, x}, {t, 0, end}, AccuracyGoal -> 5, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 5, MaxSteps -> 100000, 
  Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[Evaluate[{y[t], x[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, end}, 
 PlotStyle -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> {"y(t)", "x(t)"}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you, this worked well.